# Cleartext HTTP traffic to localhost not permitted - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, .net, kotlin, asp.net-web-api

I am making an Android app using Kotlin.
I made a .NET Web Api to which I connect to from Kotlin.

My problem is that when I send a request to my Web API, I get an exception "Cleartext HTTP traffic to localhost not permitted".

I have tried modifying my `AndroidManifest.xml` by adding `"android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`" and adding a `network_security_config.xml` (and referencing it in the manifest `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config`").

Nothing works.

My code for sending a request to my Web API:

```
const val URL = "http://localhost:24517/bar?"
const val USERNAME = "username=";
const val PASSWORD = "password=";

class BarRepo : IRepoBar{
    override fun getBarByUser(userName: String, password: String): Bar {
        val url = "$URL$USERNAME$userName&$PASSWORD$password"
        val apiResponse = URL(url).readText()
        val obj = Json.decodeFromString<Bar>(apiResponse)
        return obj
    }
}
```

The code breaks at "val apiResponse = URL(url).readText()" with the mentioned exception.

Comment: Google for allow clear text traffic then you know what you have to add to the application tag in manifest file.

Comment: `const val URL = "http://localhost:24517/bar?"` Localhost? Is your server running on the same Android device as your Android app is running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to put my local ip address to access it.